# Count number of blank rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a database of peptide sequences. I would like to add the different numbers of blank rows under the protein's name so I could analyze the data in the next step.

The blank rows are in column D, e.g. 73 blank rows for Solyc09g007080.3.1, as shown in this screenshot.
[image: this screenshot]

I found code to add specific numbers of blank rows under each row and I adjusted that code to be used with my list. It only runs for two protein names every time I run the code when I chose about 34,000 numbers in column D for the blank rows to be added.

```vb
Sub InsertSpecificNumberOfBlankRows()
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim I, xNum, xLastRow, xFstRow, xCol, xCount As Long

    Set xRg = Selection
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    xLastRow = xRg(1).End(xlDown).Row
    xFstRow = xRg.Row
    xCol = xRg.Column
    xCount = xRg.Count

    For I = xLastRow To xFstRow Step -1
        xNum = Cells(I, xCol)
        If IsNumeric(xNum) And xNum > 0 Then
            Rows(I + 1).Resize(xNum).Insert
            xCount = xCount + xNum
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code?

Comment: I have tried running each line with F8 key. Nothing change until I did it with Rows(I + 1).Resize(xNum).Insert'

Comment: By doing so, blank rows were added to only the second cell I chose (If it was this set in the screenshot, 66 blank rows were added under Solyc11g066500.2.1). So, I guess the code added blank rows under the second then the first selected cells. But I don't know why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Insert Empty Rows

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub InsertSpecificNumberOfBlankRows()

    If Not TypeOf Selection Is Range Then Exit Sub ' 'Selection' is not a range
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Selection.Columns(1)
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = srg.Worksheet
    
    Dim sLastRow As Long: sLastRow = srg.Cells(srg.Rows.Count).Row
    Dim sFirstRow As Long: sFirstRow = srg.Row
    Dim sCol As Long: sCol = srg.Column
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim sValue As Variant
    Dim irCount As Long
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = sLastRow To sFirstRow Step -1
         sValue = ws.Cells(r, sCol).Value
         If IsNumeric(sValue) Then
             If sValue >= 1 Then
                 ws.Rows(r + 1).Resize(sValue).Insert _
                      xlShiftDown, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                 irCount = irCount + sValue
             End If
         End If
    Next r
     
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Inserted " & irCount & " rows.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your input! I didn't know before I couldn't determine the selected cells as a range. I tried your code but it only adds blank rows under the first selected number (73 as in the screenshot). If I want to preselect 73, 66, 78,..., to the last number in that column before running the code, how can I do that? The idea is to add specific numbers of blank rows which indicated in column D under each row that contains the number. Thanks so much!

Comment: I don't get it. You have numbers in e.g. columns D. You select them (hold the right mouse down and drag, let go when enough). And you run the code. By the numbers, you're presenting, there should be a ton of empty rows. I have edited the code once or twice, so refresh the page and copy it now.

Comment: I got it! I selected the whole column instead of cells that contain only the numbers I want and it works! Can't thank you enough!!